# windows batch increment in specific alphanumeric string

Tags: windows, batch-file, increment, alphanumeric

I have a SOURCE textfile in which I wanted to manipulate add an incrementing alphanumerical before the semicolon as below and outputs OUTPUT.txt
SOURCE:

```
2:apple,coconut,cherry; 
3:banana,mango; 
4:cereals,nuts; 
.......... and so on
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
2:apple,coconut,cherry,TP001; 
3:banana,mango,TP002; 
4:cereals,nuts,TP003; 
.........and so on
----------
```

so I came up with the below script but it is just replacing every semicolon with ,TP001;,
can someone please help me how can I make increments to the TP001~ and so on as my desired output.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set txtfile=%1
set newfile=OUTPUT.txt
if exist "%newfile%" del /f /q "%newfile%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%txtfile%) do (
   set newline=%%a
   set newline=!newline:^;=^,TP001;!
   echo !newline! >> %newfile%
)
```

I hope you can help me with this. thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Your data has a trailing space so the code removes two characters from the end of each line.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "txtfile=%~1"
set "newfile=OUTPUT.txt"
set c=0
if exist "%newfile%" del /f /q "%newfile%"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%txtfile%") do (
   set /a c+=1
   set "n=000!c!"
   set "n=!n:~-3!"
   set "line=%%a"
   set "line=!line:~0,-2!
   >>"%newfile%" echo !line!,TP!n!;
)
```

Comment: thank 7you foxidrive,, the output is TPn:~-3; as is it does not increment.. by the way not the entire file has semicolon on it, so I dont want those parts to be inserted with TP00*; so what I wanted is to search the semicolon ; then replace it with TP00*; that is incrementing. thanks

Comment: There was a `!` missing from the end which I replaced.  It does what you asked for, so if you haven't shown correct sample data then it is not surprising that you get code that fails for data in a different format.

Comment: yeah i kinda missed that information.. i would be glad if you can help me with this stuff.. thank you..

Comment: JFTR it is very frustrating as a support person when data is shown that is obviously faked, and the OP wants help.  You provide help and 95 times out of 100 you have to redo what you've done because the data was fake and it affects the code.  See the edit I made above.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "txtfile=%~1"
set "newfile=OUTPUT.txt"
break > "%newfile%"

set "count=1000"
(for /f "usebackq delims=;" %%a in ("%txtfile%") do (
    set /a "count+=1"
    echo(%%a,TP!count:~-3!
))>"%newfile%"
```

Comment: thank you MC ND for the help..but i am supposed to search and replace the semicolon ; and replace it with TP001~ and not all lines have semicolon.. i have some other lines which are not supposed to be inserted with TP001~.. thank you. how should i suppose to do this

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set txtfile=%1
set newfile=OUTPUT.txt

if exist "%newfile%" del /f /q "%newfile%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%txtfile%) do (
   set newline=%%a
   set /a "inc+=1"
   set num=00!inc!
   set num=!num:~-3!
   set newline=!newline:^;=^,TP!
   echo !newline!!num!; >> %newfile%
)
```

Comment: thank you matt , but some part of the file has no semicolon, in which it is not supposed to add the TP; in that area.. so i needed to find the semicolon (;) and replace it as TP00*;